# Relations between tables

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have two tables (picture), AirportIn is a foreign key of AirportID, and AirportOut is also a foreign key of AirportID.

[image]

The problem is I can't make relations between these tables like this:

```
dataset.Relations.Add("AirportFlight", dataset.Tables["Airport"].Columns["AirportID"], dataset.Tables["Flight"].Columns["AirportIn"]);
dataset.Relations.Add("AirportFlight", dataset.Tables["Airport"].Columns["AirportID"], dataset.Tables["Flight"].Columns["AirportOut"]);
```

In runtime I get an error. How to solve the problem ?

Comment: The error would be nice, but saying that - surely its just Relationships need unique names?

Comment: Like this: "Relation named "AirportFlight" already consist this DataSet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the 2 relations unique names.

Comment: shoulda been obvious from the error message... but no worries.